# Slider, iteractivo al hacer clic

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Buenass, estoy necesitando ayuda para poder realizar un slider que sea interactivo con HTML y CSS, este slider debe hacerce más ancho cuando le damos clic en ella, eso creo que se podrá lograr con javaScript, además con el segundo click me permite llevar a otra ventana, lo que no sé como lograr es hacerlo más grande como se muestra en la imagen de muestra y que en el segundo clic recién lleve a otra ventana, desde ya muchas gracias.. adjunto imagen representativa

Answer (score 0):

no puedo ver esa imagen adjunta...
De todos modos, quizá algo como esto te pueda servir para empezar.

```
    <script>
        var contenedor = document.getElementById("container"); 
        contenedor.addEventListener('click',() =>{
            contenedor.style.width = "800px";
        })
    </script>
```

1- Obtienes el elemento que quieres modificar, en este caso por el id.

2- Le añades un escuchador de eventos que al hacer "click" ejecute la función que se encarga de modificar el estilo de la caja y otorgarle un width de 800px en este caso (por poner alguna dimesión).

3- Un ejemplo simple sería algo como esto:

```
 <style>
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
    .container{
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="container"></div>
    <script>
        var contenedor = document.getElementById("container");
        contenedor.addEventListener('click',() =>{
            contenedor.style.width = "800px";
        })        
    </script>
</body>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Buenas @manupnro, ahora verifique y volví a colocar la imagen... desde ya muchas gracias, voy a seguir intentando!!!